# Toggle multiple div visibility on hover and click

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, hover

I am trying to achieve two simple effects : showing/hiding an `<ul>` element on mouse over and on click.

There are several methods to obtain that effect, here is a working example on jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/66y4J/1/

As you can see, there are still some problems :

1. Multiple divs have the same id. And only the first `<div>` works on the hovering-part. I think I need some "context" in the jQuery code
2. Whereas in the click event, it reveals/hides all `<div>` presenting the same id.

Here is the HTML :

```
<div id="open-on-hover">
<h2>Section Title h2 - Hover</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 4</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="open-on-click">
<h2>Section Title h2 - Click</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the jQuery part :

```
$('#open-on-hover>ul').hide();

$( "#open-on-hover" ).hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('ul').hide();
});



$('#open-on-click>ul').hide();

$("#open-on-click>h2").click(
    function() {
        $('#open-on-click>h2+ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: why not use a common class for event handlers? And where are duplicate Ids? Your markup consists of just 2 divs with different IDs

Comment: Repeating IDs!! IDs must be **unique** [**See**](http://jsfiddle.net/Av7aQ/)

Comment: ARG ! You're so right, how could I not use a class ? :-)

Comment: `open-on-hover` and `open-on-click` are not repeating IDs I guess

Comment: In modern browsers you dont even need javascript for this http://jsfiddle.net/66y4J/3/ :P

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I know I shouldn't propagate bad practices here but I must mention that it is quite possible to handle duplicate IDs on a page.  I had to do this once on code written by someone else, it would have been too much for me to change IDs to classes.  But just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr If you want to set duplicate IDs then use `.data()` attributes to that it can be `data-id=yourID`, And FYI: it's **NEVER BEEN A GOOD PRACTICE TO HAVE DUPLICATE IDs in a single PAGE** !

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I already said that it's not a good practice to have duplicate IDs and "just because you can doesn't mean you should".  But sometimes,  it is too late to avoid this problem by using different classes, because someone else started using duplicate IDs long before you realise it.  In such situations, you can use `$("[id=myId]")` to select all the elements with specified ID.  Normal `$('#myId')` will select only first instance of `#myId`.  ***NOTE:*** this information is for academic purposes only(and sometimes to save your butt).

Answer (score 1):

A bit less code: http://jsfiddle.net/kasperoo/66y4J/8/

```
$( ".hoverReveal" ).hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('ul').hide();
    }
);

<div class="hoverReveal">
<h2>Section Title h2 - Hover</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Edited it to make less mental hover, but this is just basic idea :)

Comment: A CSS pseudo element would be better idea for hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution for modern browsers (requires `:checked` and `:hover` pseudo classes). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66y4J/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="open-on-hover">
<h2>Section Title h2 - Hover</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
        <li>Element 3</li>
        <li>Element 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="open-on-click">
    <label for="trigger1">
        <h2>Section Title h2 - Click</h2>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="trigger1" class="trigger" />
    <ul>
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
        <li>Element 3</li>
        <li>Element 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.open-on-hover > ul {
    display: none;
}
.open-on-hover:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.open-on-click > .trigger {
    display: none;
}
.open-on-click > .trigger:checked + ul {
    display: block;
}
.open-on-click > .trigger + ul {
    display: none;
}
```